# How to Cross Compile using Eclipse C/C++ IDE?

Tags: gcc, eclipse, shared-libraries

I setup Eclipse C/C++ IDE on Linux desktop to cross compile programs on to a Linux RT platform using a GCC cross compiler.

Now I am trying to set up Eclipse C/C++ IDE on Windows to achieve the same.
But I run into issues when I try to set Linker options.

Because on Linux, if I have to link a library `libABCD.so.10.0.0` I just have to add `ABCD` in linker options, and create a symbolic link `ABCD.so -> libABCD.so.10.0.0`

Now, how do I solve the same issue on Windows, How can I create symbolic links on windows ?
Directly specifying the absolute path of library didn't work as the compiler prefixes `-l` to library names (which can't be found).
i

Comment: I guess this site is helpful, http://www.acmesystems.it/foxg20_eclipse_windows_c

Comment: This is on-topic on [su] or [so], but not here, since you're asking about using programs on Windows.

Comment: @Networker Sorry, it didn't help as the article doesn't discuss about linker options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem.
Symbolic links can be created on windows using the command

> mklink

This functions exactly  the same way as `ln` command on Linux to create symbolic links.
So, if you have a library `libABCD.so.10.0.0` and if you are linking to this through GCC cross compiler tool chain from an eclipse editor, you need to create the symbolic link.

> mklink /H libABCD.so libABCD.so.10.0.0

> dir

libABCD.so

libABCD.so.10.0.0

Hence the linker successfully links to this library.